# Maximum Count Range Intersection (in T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Let's say I have a table with a bunch of dates, e.g.:

```
declare @tbl table {
    idx int primary key,
    startdate datetime,
    enddate datetime
}
```

And I want to find the largest set of rows where startdate and enddate intersect (in the real world, the start date and end date represents start and end times for events, and I need to find the maximum # of events occurring simultaneously).

In another programming language I might sort all entries by startdate, then iterate through each entry once, building a temporary set of intersections (keeping track of the largest set generated).  But I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to express this in T-SQL.  help!

Oh, and it's SQL Server 2000. :(

Comment: Intersections, what do you require, and what have you come up with

Comment: I think my requirements above are pretty clear.  I want the largest set of events that occur simultaneously.   Two rows "a" and "b"  interesect whens a.startdate <= b.enddate and a.enddate >= b.startdate.  

every solution I have tried so far has been sort of hacky.  that's why I am asking dear lazyweb.  :)

Comment: well based on the question, if you googled, http://www.sqlhacks.com/index.php/Dates/Dates would have been there

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but none of those links has an answer to my question.  And yes, I googled.

Comment: Show some luv, give a small set of data, table structure and a potential query you tried (as i see from posts below (duh???) that you have tried before) and we will try to help...

Comment: what is the used precision of your datetime columns? day, hour, minute, seconds, ... smaller?

Answer (score 3):

*Updated to remove the union all*

```
declare @tbl table (
idx int identity(1,1) primary key,    
startdate datetime,    
enddate datetime);

insert into @tbl (startdate, enddate) 
select '2009-01-01', '2009-01-05'
union all select '2009-01-02', '2009-01-04'
union all select '2009-01-01', '2009-01-03'
union all select '2009-01-03', '2009-01-06'
union all select '2009-01-04', '2009-01-07'
union all select '2009-01-05', '2009-01-08'

select idx, startdate
   , (select sum(in_or_out) 
from (
   select case when startdate<=all_events.startdate then 1 else 0 end
     + case when enddate <= all_events.startdate then -1 else 0 end as in_or_out
   from @tbl 
   where startdate <= all_events.startdate
     or enddate <= all_events.startdate) as previous
) as concurent
from @tbl all_events
order by startdate
```

This gives the timeline of start session, with the count of concurent sessions at the moment new session starts:

```
idx startdate   concurent
3   2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 2
1   2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 2
2   2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 3
4   2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 3
5   2009-01-04 00:00:00.000 3
6   2009-01-05 00:00:00.000 3
```

To get the original request (set of concurent sessions with max concurency) you need to run this query twice, once to get the max concurent sessions and once to get the start dates of the sessions that have max concurent times, then you must get those sessions.

**Updated**

OK, so here the one single query that retrieves the max concurent sessions. I changed the test data to remove ambibuos overlaps of end and start:

```
declare @tbl table (
idx int identity(1,1) primary key,    
startdate datetime,    
enddate datetime);

insert into @tbl (startdate, enddate) 
select '2009-01-01', '2009-01-04 23:59:59'
union all select '2009-01-02', '2009-01-03 23:59:59'
union all select '2009-01-01', '2009-01-02 23:59:59'
union all select '2009-01-03', '2009-01-03 23:59:59'
union all select '2009-01-04', '2009-01-04 23:59:59'
union all select '2009-01-05', '2009-01-05 23:59:59'


select max_concurent_starts.startdate as concurentdate
  , session.*
from (
  select *
  ,(
        select sum(in_or_out) 
        from (
            select case when startdate<=all_events.startdate then 1 else 0 end
                + case when enddate <= all_events.startdate then -1 else 0 end 
                as in_or_out
          from @tbl 
          where startdate <= all_events.startdate
              or enddate <= all_events.startdate) as previous
    ) as concurent
  from @tbl all_events) as max_concurent_starts
  join @tbl as session 
     on session.startdate <= max_concurent_starts.startdate 
     and session.enddate >= max_concurent_starts.startdate
  where concurent = (
  select top 1 concurent
  from (
      select (
          select sum(in_or_out) 
          from (
              select case when startdate<=all_events.startdate then 1 else 0 end
                  + case when enddate <= all_events.startdate then -1 else 0 end 
                  as in_or_out
            from @tbl 
            where startdate <= all_events.startdate
                or enddate <= all_events.startdate) as previous
      ) as concurent
    from @tbl all_events) as all_events_with_concurent
    order by concurent desc)
  order by concurentdate, startdate;
```

This gives a result like:

```
concurentdate   idx startdate   enddate
2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 3   2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 2009-01-02 23:59:59.000
2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 1   2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 2009-01-04 23:59:59.000
2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 2   2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 2009-01-03 23:59:59.000
2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 1   2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 2009-01-04 23:59:59.000
2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 2   2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 2009-01-03 23:59:59.000
2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 4   2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 2009-01-03 23:59:59.000
```

which reads as follows: on `2009-01-02 00:00:00` there were 3 concurent sessions (3, 1 and 2) with they respective starts and ends. There is a tie, on `2009-01-03 00:00:00` there were also 3 concurent sessions (1, 2 and 4) with their respective starts and ends.

Performance milage may vary. The query can be written 1 million times simpler in SQL 2005 using CTEs.

Comment: sweet: nice idea to flatten the ranges into a simple list

Comment: in case you wonder why mine is so fat compared with charles's is because of the handling of ties.

Answer (score 2):

try this (it's close to what you want I think...

```
Select Distinct EventId 
From EventTable Et
Join  (Select Top 1 RunDate, Count(*) DateCount
       From 
          (Select Distinct StartDate RunDate
           From EventTable
               Union  
           Select Distinct EndDate RunDate
           From EventTable) A
         Join EventTable E
            On A.RunDate Between E.StartDate And E.EndDate
       Group By RunDate
       Order By Count(*) Desc) Z
   On Z.RunDate Between Et.StartDate and Et.EndDate
```

oh, If your dates have date and Time in them, then replace all the dates herein with actual date portion only (strip off the time)

```
Select Distinct EventId 
From EventTable Et
Join  (Select Top 1 RunDate, Count(*) DateCount
       From 
          (Select Distinct DateAdd(day, 0, DateDiff(day, 0, StartDate)) RunDate
           From EventTable
               Union  
           Select Distinct DateAdd(day, 0, DateDiff(day, -1, EndDate)) RunDate
           From EventTable) A
         Join EventTable E
            On A.RunDate Between DateAdd(day, 0, DateDiff(day, 0, E.StartDate))
                             and DateAdd(day, 0, DateDiff(day, -1, E.EndDate))
       Group By RunDate
       Order By Count(*) Desc) Z
   On Z.RunDate Between DateAdd(day, 0, DateDiff(day, 0, Et.StartDate))
                    and DateAdd(day, 0, DateDiff(day, -1, Et.EndDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
DECLARE @idx INT,
        @startdate DATETIME,
    @enddate DATETIME,  
        @prev_enddate DATETIME,
        @counter INT,
    @counter_max INT

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT idx, startdate,enddate 
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY startdate,enddate

OPEN db_cursor   

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @idx, @startdate, @enddate
SET @prev_enddate = @enddate
SET @counter = 0
SET @counter_max = 0

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
IF @startdate < @prev_enddate
BEGIN
    SET @counter = @counter + 1 
    IF @counter > @counter_max
    BEGIN
        SET @counter_max = @counter
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @counter = 1
END

SET @prev_enddate = @enddate
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @idx, @startdate, @enddate           
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SELECT @counter_max
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty short, easy to understand and works fine:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindEvents
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE dates_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT
            startdate AS thedate, 1 AS change
        FROM
            dates
        UNION
        SELECT
            enddate AS thedate, - 1 AS change
        FROM
            dates
        ORDER BY 
            thedate ASC;

        DECLARE @max INT;
        DECLARE @thedate DATETIME;
        DECLARE @change INT;
        DECLARE @current INT;

        SET @max = 0;
        SET @current = 0;

    OPEN dates_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM dates_cursor INTO @thedate, @change

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @current = @current + @change;
        IF (@current > @max)
        BEGIN
            SET @max = @current;
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM dates_cursor INTO @thedate, @change
    END

    CLOSE dates_cursor
    DEALLOCATE dates_cursor

    SELECT @max;
END
```

Comment: I think that looping with a cursor is slower than having a query doing it